# smartparens, just disable automatic insertion of parentheis

Tags: smartparens

I 'd like to try smartparens but don't like the automatic parenthesis insertion.

Can I turn it off that feature only?
Or is it meaningless to keep the mode after I disable the feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`smartparens` isn't really designed to be used that way, but it does have some settings you can tweak. Setting `(setq sp-autoinsert-pair nil)` will disable auto-inserting pairs. For more auto-pair related settings see https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/issues/614.